# Get namespace from callee intercepted on exception

Tags: python

I wanted to intercept exception and do some reports while executing Python code. Mainly I wanted to export the namespace of the code when exception occurred.

What I can do is following:

I have file `test.py` that will raise exception:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i > 5:
        j
    else:
        i
```

And file `check.py` that will intercept exception and launch debugger when test script is passed as argument:

```
import sys, pdb

try:
    __import__(sys.argv[1])
except Exception as e:
    pdb.post_mortem(sys.exc_info()[2])
```

That's nice.

Further I can locate the frame in callee where exception occurred, with `inspect` module:

```
import sys, inspect

try:
    __import__(sys.argv[1])
except Exception as e:
    callee_frame_tuple = inspect.trace()[1]
    print callee_frame_tuple
```

output:

```
(<frame object at 0x00C9B260>, 'C:\\Temp\\test.py', 3, '<module>', ['        j\n'], 0)
```

and use it to get information about the frame with `getargvalues()`:

```
import sys, inspect

try:
    __import__(sys.argv[1])
except Exception as e:
    callee_frame_tuple = inspect.trace()[1]
    inspect.getargvalues(callee_named_tuple[0])[3]['__builtins__']['locals']()
```

output:

```
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>,
 '__doc__': None,
 '__file__': 'C:\\Temp\\check.py',
 '__name__': '__main__',
 '__package__': None,
 'e': NameError("name 'j' is not defined",),
 'inspect': <module 'inspect' from 'C:\Python27\lib\inspect.pyc'>,
 'sys': <module 'sys' (built-in)>}
```

so I got locals for `check.py` and not for callee `test.py` although I used it's frame reference as `getargvalues()` argument.

Does anyone know how to get callee namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from the formatted traceback that Python prints, but because you're using `__import__`, you actually get two separate `traceback` objects. You can access the second one like this...

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint

try:
    __import__(sys.argv[1])
except Exception as e:
    my_traceback = sys.exc_info()[2]

# Print locals for my stack frame
#pprint(my_traceback.tb_frame.f_locals)

# Print locals for other stack frame
other_traceback = my_traceback.tb_next
pprint(other_traceback.tb_frame.f_locals)
```

There's a bit more info about the `traceback` and `frame` objects in [section 3.2](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) of the Python docs.

---

**Update**

> That's the same object as `inspect.getargvalues(callee_named_tuple[0])`
>   above, so I wasn't aware that that is actually callee locals, while I
>   dig into it.

You're right. I'm not really familiar with the `inspect` module - I tend to just access the `traceback` attributes directly.

> I was expecting that I can find namespace dict where `i` variable has
>   value 6 as then exception occurred, while this way I get `i=None`. Is
>   there no way that get the namespace of callee?

I noticed that too. It seems to be some oddity of using `__import__`, because it works fine when using [`execfile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile). The following script...

```
import sys

try:
    execfile(sys.argv[1])
except Exception as e:
    the_value_of_i = sys.exc_info()[2].tb_next.tb_frame.f_locals['i']
    print 'The value of "i" was "%r"' % the_value_of_i
```

...yields...

```
The value of "i" was "6"
```

Comment: That's the same object as `inspect.getargvalues(callee_named_tuple[0])[3]` above, so I wasn't aware that that is actually callee locals, while I dig into it. I was expecting that I can find namespace dict where `i` variable (from test.py) has value 6 as then exception occurred, while this way I get `i=None`. Is there no way to get the namespace of callee?